# Angular - @ViewChild from My Module

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, module, viewchild

my question is regarding Angular 2/4/5 module.

Can't make @ViewChild work while using it from a module, the child is undefined. before I was using it as a simple component and it worked fine.
*Tried @ViewChildren also... same

code samples -

app.module.ts -

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MyNewModule} from './modules/MyNewModule/MyNewModule.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MyNewModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyNewModule} from './modules/MyNewModule/MyNewModule.module';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<button (click)="Print()">Print child</button>
             <my-new-module></my-new-module>
            `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private MyModule:MyNewModule){}

  ngOnInit(){}

  Print(){
   this.MyModule.Print();
  }

}
```

modules/MyNewModule/MyNewModule.module -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MyNewModule} from './MyNewModule.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [MyNewModule],
  providers: [MyNewModule],
  exports: [MyNewModule],
})
export class MyNewModule{ }
```

modules/MyNewModule/MyNewModule.ts-

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-new-module',
  template:`<ng-template #Container></ng-template>`
})
export class MyNewModule implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('Container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) private container: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(){}

ngOnInit(){}

Print(){
  console.log(this.container); => undefined
}



}
```

When trying to search for an answer online only solution I found was to try @ViewChildren, or that it may happen cuz the view hasn't init yet. so I even tried to do it in a timeout of 5 seconds... same result.
Again using the same code but as a simple app and not module worked fine.

Thanks for reading ! :)

Comment: Where do you call `Print()`?

Comment: Why is your component named `MyNewModule` instead of `MyNewComponent`? I think it is causing some problems for you. Also, you can't put a component into `providers` array.

Comment: @Und3rTow fixed, added to app.component.ts template :)

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I'm not, its simply for this demo.  taking it off the providers array ggives me an errror - StaticInjectorError

Comment: why are you even trying to inject an angular module into a component?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I want to publish it as a library . trying to do that as a sandbox to check if it works. 
first step was using it as a component which was fine.

Comment: oh just realized you have a module and a component with the same (class) name

Comment: Provide a plunkr please

Comment: @Ben because you can't inject a component in your constructors like that. You should use `ViewChild` in your `app.component` to get an instance of `MyNewModule`

Comment: Can you please elaborate? 
My end goal is to create and publish a library. must be a way that my module will do that without having to require the app to do that ? @BunyaminCoskuner

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to with your library. What kind of component library are you planning on publishing? If you explain it in more details, I may help you.

Comment: I'm doing it for the sake of learning and in the future being able to re-use parts of code that I write in other projects. for this example its just a simple module with a single component in it, and the component has ng-content inside so I can add lets say html into this ng-content from the module it self, not from the app.component. just couldn't find any guide that does what I need... sadly , thanks mate@BunyaminCoskuner

Comment: Okay, I understand. I'll post something soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood from the comments, you want to create a feature module for a component(s) and reuse it among your projects.

I suggest you take a look at this component library [PrimeNg](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) and their [Github](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng) page. They have well-designed architecture, i.e. a feature module for a component.

Let's start from scratch and build our reusable component.

I created a new app with angular-cli

`ng new my-proj`

Then I created a feature module for a component I will develop later on. Let's call it `MyComponent`

`ng generate module my-component`

Then created a component with same name

`ng generate component my-component`

Then I edit `MyComponent` as following

my-component.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
        <h1>My Component</h1>
        <div #container>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

    @ViewChild('container') container: ElementRef;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.container);
    }

    // this life cycle method is called after projected content is initialized.
    ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log(this.container);
    }

    someMethod() {
    // do something ...
    }
}
```

Then I export it from `my-component.module.ts` as following

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [MyComponentComponent],
    exports: [MyComponentComponent]
})
export class MyComponentModule { }
```

Then, imported this module in my `app.module.ts` and used this component in `app.component`

Also, if you want to access `my-component` within `app.component`, you can use `ViewChild`

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <button (click)="onButtonClick()">Click me</button>
        <my-component>
            <div>This is from app component</div>
        </my-component>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {

    @ViewChild(MyComponentComponent) myComponent: MyComponentComponent;

    onButtonClick() {
        this.myComponent.someMethod();
    }
}
```

I hope this clarifies it for you

**Edit**

For publishing your library, you can check this article out:

[Building an Angular 4 Component Library with the Angular CLI and ng-packagr](https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e)

Also, for people who'll use your library to import your component and modules from same file, you can export it from your module as following

my-component.module.ts

```
export {MyComponentComponent} from './my-component.component.ts';

@NgModule({
    ...
})
export class MyComponentModule {}
```

To import it in your `app.component`,

app.component.ts

`import {MyComponentComponent} from 'your-library/my-component.module'`;

You can import the module from same location

app.module.ts

`import {MyComponentModule} from 'your-library/my-component.module';`

Comment: Amazing, this was exactly what I needed! the idea of @ViewChild of  MyComponentComponent Is what I was missing, now I just need to build and publish my modules to npm.
Thanks alot for the informative answer

Comment: @Ben I'm glad you liked my answer. I updated it and added an link. You can use ng-packagr for that.

Comment: I got another question If you can... apparently MyComponentComponent needs to be imported inside app.component.ts in order to use it. isn't the whole idea is that I add it to the module exports array? how can I use it without seperatlly import it from another location?

Comment: Well, yeah you have to add `import {MyComponentComponent} from '../my-component/my-component.component.ts` because you use its type within your code. Typescript needs to know where it is coming from. But it is different than Angular import. This is just ES6 module import.

Comment: I omitted `import` statements for the sake of simplicity but you need them.

Comment: so if I want to publish it as a library for future use. I'l have to import both the module and the component? 
isn't there a way so I can import both from same location or something? saw librarys which work that way

Comment: Again, exactly what I needed. Thanks alot for your time Bunyamin

Comment: thanks , this solution saved lot of time, i was missing the export part in my module .

Answer (score 0):

You need a ViewChild to reference TemplateRef and ViewContainerRef for your template.  Use a  `ComponentResolverFactory` to create a component, then use the component viewRef to create an embedded view.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'widget',
    template: '<ng-template #view></ng-template>'
})

export class WidgetComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('view', { read: ViewContainerRef }) view: ViewContainerRef;
    @ViewChild('view') template: TemplateRef<any>;

    constructor(private factory: ComponentResolverFactory, private viewRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

    ngOnInit() { 
         let component = ... some Type<any>...
         let componentFactory = this.factory.resolveComponentFactory(component);
         let ref:ComponentRef<any> = view.createComponent(componentFactory);
         this.factory.create(this.view, this.message.component);
         this.viewRef.createEmbeddedView(this.template);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do I need a ViewContainerRef to template? why do I need to generate a component for it?
Wouldn't it be enouggh to just add 
    <my-new-module></my-new-module>

to app.component template?